# Dehn's Word Problem for different generating sets

Tags: group-theory, word-problem

Dehn's Word Problem $DWP(G, S)$ asks whether a word in $(S \cup S^{-1})^*$ is the identity in $G$ for a Group $G$ with a finite generating set $S$ of $G$.

I'm new to word problems and one of the first questions that came to my mind is whether we can solve $DWP(G, T)$ given that we can solve $DWP(S, G)$ where $S$ and $T$ are two finite generating sets.

From what I have seen in the literature (e.g. [here](https://www.eti.uni-siegen.de/ti/veroeffentlichungen/cwp-brief.pdf), Lemma 2.13) we can reduce $DWP(S, G)$ to $DWP(S, T)$, but the proofs rely on having homomorphism $$h: (S \cup S^{-1})^∗ \to
(T \cup T^{−1})^∗ $$

But if all we have is an algorithm for $DWP(G,S)$, and not $h$, is there really anything we can say about $DWP(G, T)$? What if $S$ is a subset of $T$?

Comment: Your use of the topology terminology "homeomorphism" makes no sense in this context. And you have an unnecessary use of the $*$ operator in your expression for $h$. In fact what is needed is a function $h : S \cup S^{-1} \to (T \cup T^{-1})^*$ such that for each $s \in S \cup S^{-1}$, the word $h(s) \in (T \cup T^{-1})^*$ represents the same element of $G$ as the letter $s$. And if you think about it, to require that $h$ be given is not only reasonable, but it is quite necessary in order to properly formulate the problem.

Comment: I think for this question to make sense you need to be more precise is specifying exactly what your input is. For example, how do you input the elements of $T$? If all you are given is ${\rm DWP}(G,S)$, then the only feasible way to input the elements of $T$ is as words in $(S \cup S^{-1})^*$, but in that case you can immediately convert an element of $G$ given as a word in generators $T$ to a word in generators $S$, and there is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First write each element $t_i\in T$ as a word in $(S\cup S^{-1})^\ast$: $$t_i=s^{(i)}_{1}\cdots s^{(i)}_{n_i};\quad s^{(i)}_j\in S\cup S^{-1}$$

Now, given two words $w=w(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ and $w'=w'(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ in $(T\cup T^{-1})^\ast$; we want to test whether $\overline{w}=\overline{w'}$ in $G$(here I use $\overline{x}$ to denote the element of $G$ represented by the word $x$).

Substituting the expressions for the $t_i$ in terms of $S\cup S^{-1}$ into $w$ and $w'$ gives new words representing the same elements as $\overline{w}$ and $\overline{w'}$, call these $u$ and $u'$ respectively. Now $\overline{w}=\overline{w'}$ if and only if $\overline{u}=\overline{u'}$, which we can check using our solution to $DWP(G,S)$.

This is the same proof as given in Lemma 2.13, I have just written out the homomorphism $h\colon (S\cup S^{-1})^\ast\to(T\cup T^{-1})^\ast$ explicitly by rewriting the $t_i$'s in terms of the elements of $S$.

Comment: But in order to rewrite each $t$ in $T$ as a product of elements in $S$ we would first need to solve $DWP(G, S \cup T)$ right?

Comment: No this shouldn't be a problem, but exactly why it isn't a problem will depend on the exact set-up you are using. When applying the algorithm you assume you have to solve $DWP(G,S)$, what form do you assume you input words are in? If you assume that you start off knowing how to express every element of $G$ as words over $S$ then there is no issue because then _a priori_ you assume you have the elements of $T$ in this form. If you have a different set-up / starting assumptions in mind then let me know what they are and I will try to edit my answer to address that case.